# How to access key values in ordered dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

How to access the values in this Ordered Dictionary..I want to access the values inside the cost_price which is 0.92.

```
OrderedDict([('0', OrderedDict([('cost_price', '0.92'), ('quantity', '0'), ('sell_price', '1.69'), ('text', '6oz')]))])
```

Comment: Same as normal `Dictionary`.

Comment: What have you tried? What does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `next` with a generator expression, if you know in advance there is only one entry with your cost_price.

As noted, this is no different to an ordinary dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([('0', OrderedDict([('cost_price', '0.92'), ('quantity', '0'), ('sell_price', '1.69'), ('text', '6oz')]))])

res = next((d[i] for i in d if d[i]['cost_price'] == '0.92'), None)
```

Result:

```
OrderedDict([('cost_price', '0.92'),
             ('quantity', '0'),
             ('sell_price', '1.69'),
             ('text', '6oz')])
```

To get all cost_price values by key:

```
res = {k: d[k]['cost_price'] for k in d}

# {'0': '0.92'}
```