# How to access key values of ordered dict in django serializer query

Tags: python, django, ordereddictionary

I work with Django-Rest api and have serializer that returns me the data like this

> my_ordered = [OrderedDict([('idx', '1231233'), ('rock', None), ('Email', 'albundy@abc.com')]), OrderedDict([('idx', '1212333'), ('paper', None), ('Email', 'peggybundy@abc.com')])]

```
type(my_ordered)    
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
```

I tried to access its 'Email' key like this

```
for trainer, training in my_ordered.items():
     print(training['Email'])
```

NameError: name 'OrderedDict' is not defined

Also tried

```
import collections
my_ordered = [collections.OrderedDict([('idx', '1231233'), ('rock', None), ('Email', 'albundy@abc.com')]), collections.OrderedDict([('idx', '1212333'), ('paper', None), ('Email', 'peggybundy@abc.com')])]
#my_ordered.keys()[2]
for trainer, training in my_ordered.items():
     print(training['Email'])

my_ordered.keys()[2]
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

but this also not helped.

[How to access key values in ordered dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627714/how-to-access-key-values-in-ordered-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

```
my_ordered = [collections.OrderedDict(...)]
```

Your `my_ordered` is actually a list of `OrderedDict`s. You can get to one with in example:

```
my_ordered[0].keys()
```